# jQuery code to Ajax convert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to convert the below jQuery code to Ajax is it possible ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("#co-shipping-method-form .buttons-set button.button").click(function () {
            var shippingSelectedValue = $j("input[name='shipping_method']:checked").val();
            if(shippingSelectedValue == 'freeshipping_freeshipping' ){
           $j("#customtest_modal_id").show();
            }
        });
        $j("a.reset-customtest").click(function () {
            $j("#customtest_modal_id, #checkout-step-shipping_method").show();
            $j("#checkout-step-payment").hide();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "convert"? Do you know what Ajax is used for?

Comment: Ajax is a method to call a backend function to return date.  Your code is only a binding to click event.....

Comment: @hallleron: i am not aware of ajax that much : what i need is i have  one button click i want to execute the above logic can you let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand concept of AJAX.

Here are things AJAX can do for you:
- Read data from a web server - after the page has loaded
- Update a web page without reloading the page
- Send data to a web server - in the background

In short, AJAX is a way to transport data via XML

Comment: i am not aware of ajax that much : what i need is i have one button click i want to execute the above logic can you let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it. 
First, you need to define a function with your logic, like

```
function clickButtonSet() {
  //you code here
}
```

Then, in your html, you add an action onclick into .button-set

```
<button class="button-set" onclick="clickButtonSet()"> Click Me </button>
```

The same with button .reset-customerset

Try it :)